# Elapsed time in Google Analytics not correct

Tags: ios, google-analytics-4

We are using GA4 on iOS to measure, amongst other metrics, how long does a user spend on each view. We are seeing elapsed times of days, where it should be minutes or seconds. Has anybody come across this problem using GA4?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_AhsKuNrWk 7:56) Elapsed Time is not an average but a sum. So basically each time a user goes from step 1 to step 2 in the funnel, this time gets added up.

I don't know if there's a way to check the average/median of Elapsed Time, I've looked for any info online and couldn't find any, which is unfortunate - in my opinion the average is way more useful than the sum.
And as far as I know there's no way to display the count of how many times this change from step 1 to step 2 happened, so you can't calculate the average manually even if you wanted to